# How to delete a specific and not constant part of a string

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I would like to cut this string

```
Dim str = "BMW{1}/X5{5}/image"
```

like this

```
Dim Brand = "BMW"
Dim idBrand= 1
Dim Model = "X5"
Dim Resource = "image"
```

for the / part I can easily do  str.Split("/") but for the {1} I don't know if there is a special function or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good place to use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
Dim str = "BMW{1}/X5{5}/image"
Dim regex as new RegEx("(?<brand>[^{]+){(?<idbrand>\d+)}\/(?<model>[^{]+){[^}]+}\/(?<resource>.*)")
Dim match = regex.Match(str)
```

`match` is now an object containing various bits of information about what it's found.  Since I added [named capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) into the regex (`brand`, `idbrand`, `model` and `resource`), you can now access those within the `match` object:

```
Dim Brand = match.Groups("brand").Value
Dim idBrand= match.Groups("idbrand").Value
Dim Model = match.Groups("model").Value
Dim Resource = match.Groups("resource").Value
```

There is lots of information on regex available on the internet, one resource I find useful is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gO1gG8/1), which will give you an explanation of what the regex is doing on the right hand side.

Comment: I didn't know you could name Regex groups! O.o